# How do I prepare a painted wall before applying an orange peel texture?

Tags: drywall

I have a sheet rock wall that had been primed and painted.  I would like to put a orange peel texture over the top. What do I need to do to prep the wall if anything?

Answer (score 1):

If there is **any** sheen, de-gloss by sanding then thoroughly clean the wall.